# Divide and Multiply value-of-select in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, division, multiplication

Just want to multiply the value-of select by 1000000 after div, very new to this; I'm sure it's a easy question for someone. Thanks in advance.

```
<xsl:value-of select="AbsolutePos/@x div 80" />
```

Wanting to multiply by 1000000, don't think this is right, hence is returning incorrect value

```
<xsl:value-of select="AbsolutePos/@x div 80 * 1000000" />
```

Continued: Have the following XML

```
<AbsolutePos x="-1.73624e+006" y="-150800" z="40000"></AbsolutePos>
```

Needing to change to

```
<PInsertion>-21703,-1885,500</PInsertion>
```

Using XSL

```
<PInsertion><xsl:value-of select="AbsolutePos/@x div 80 * 1000000" />,<xsl:value-of select="AbsolutePos/@y div 80" />,<xsl:value-of select="AbsolutePos/@z div 80" /></PInsertion>
```

Though receiving

```
<PInsertion>NaN,-1885,500</PInsertion>
```

Suppose to take the X value and divide it by 80 then multiply by 10000 to return -21703

Comment: Your code seems alright. What is the value of @x?

Comment: "*hence is returning incorrect value*" A specific example, including the input and the received result would be useful.

Comment: Made amendments above to my initial question, thanks heaps.

Comment: Not all XSLT processors will recognize that `-1.73624e+006` is a number.

Comment: That's where it's failing and returning; <PInsertion>NaN,-1885,500</PInsertion> ,anything I could do?

Comment: Which engine are you using? Where are you getting the input XML and can it change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your XSLT processor does not recognize scientific notation, you will have to do the work yourself - for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="AbsolutePos">
    <PInsertion>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </PInsertion>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="AbsolutePos/@*">
    <xsl:variable name="num">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'e+')">
                <xsl:variable name="factor">
                    <xsl:call-template name="power-of-10">
                        <xsl:with-param name="exponent" select="substring-after(., 'e+')"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., 'e+') * $factor" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$num div 80" />
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="power-of-10">
    <xsl:param name="exponent"/>
    <xsl:param name="result" select="1"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$exponent">
            <xsl:call-template name="power-of-10">
                <xsl:with-param name="exponent" select="$exponent - 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="result" select="$result * 10"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this is a simplified example that will not handle negative exponents.

---

### Edit

If your input **always** follows the pattern of (only) @x being in the form of `#.####e+006` then you can make this much simpler by taking the value of `substring-before(AbsolutePos/@x, 'e+')` and multiplying it by 12500 (i.e. 10^6 / 80).